# Unable to get the custom field value in WorkItem

Tags: excel, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am having custom field value in Excel. When I am trying to publish to TFS2018, I am getting empty values.

Tried adding field names in WIT file (XML format) and imported to the project. I am able to see the custom field in TFS also.

```xml
<FIELD name="OldID" refname="Test.OldID" type="Integer">
  <HELPTEXT>Defines OLDID.</HELPTEXT>  
  <WHENNOTCHANGED field="Test.OldID">
     <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
   </WHENNOTCHANGED>
  <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
</FIELD>
```

I have Custom field value in Excel which should be populated in TFS 2018 while publish it.

[image: Excel]

[image: TFS]

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have identified the value to be imported from excel to TFS custom field.

Created a new query including custom field, then open that query from Visual Studio in excel.

Once opened, copy the value to custom field and publish it.

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtntN.png)

[Work Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7WUh.png)